# YuiCompressor.net - adding javascript source map links

Tags: yui-compressor, source-maps

We are currently using YuiCompressor.net in our build steps to minify scripts contained in our corporate CDN. Is it possible to hook into the minification process to add links to javascript source maps, so we can debug minified scripts in the browsers?

Answer (score 0):

No.  Not at this time.  However, I did enter a feature request:

https://github.com/PureKrome/YUICompressor.NET/issues/12

Maybe you (or someone else) can propose a solution via pull request?